# why is my navbar not highlighting?

Tags: html, css, menu, blocking, menubar

Why are the first menus not highlighting or but the last two are. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the image but if it does I have no idea how to fix it.

My HTML:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Practise.css"/>
    <title>Practise</title>     
    </head>
    <img src="404SQN logo.png" width="1250" class="logo"/>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="drop">
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <div class="dropdownContain">
                <div class="dropOut">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About 404SQN</li>
                        <li>About AAFC</li>
                        <li>What to Expect</li>
                        <li>Discipline</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: 0;font-size: 100%;vertical-align: baseline;background: transparent;}body {line-height: 1;}ol, ul {list-style: none;}blockquote, q {quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {content: '';content: none;} /* remember to define focus styles! */ :focus {outline: 0;} /* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */ins {text-decoration: none;}del {text-decoration: line-through;} /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */ table {border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;}

    .logo {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -27.5em;
    top: -22em;
    z-index: -1;
}
    /*---------- BODY --------------------------------*/

    body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}

       a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*---------- Wrapper --------------------*/

nav {
    width: 95%;
    height: 4em;
    background: #003C82;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 6em;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

ul li {
margin-top: -0.5em;
    font-family:‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding .05s linear;
    -ms-transition: padding .05s linear;
    -o-transition: padding .05s linear;
    transition: padding .05s linear;
}
ul li.drop {
    position: relative;
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 80px;
    color: #777;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}

.dropOut .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
    top: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.dropdownContain {
    width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px; /* half of width */
    top: -400px;
}
.dropOut {
    width: 160px;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
}

.dropOut ul {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.dropOut ul li {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    padding: 12px 0 10px 15px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    color: #777;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    transition: background .1s ease-out;
}

.dropOut ul li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

ul li:hover a { color: white; }
ul li:hover .dropdownContain { top: 65px; }
ul li:hover .underline { border-bottom-color: #777; }
ul li:hover .dropOut { opacity: 1; margin-top: 8px; }

/*Search Bar Starts Here*/
#tw-form-outer {
float: right;
position: absolute;
right: 1.8em;
top: 1em;

}
#tw-form{
margin-top: 1em;
font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border: #aaa 1px solid;
background: #DDDDDD;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4 0%, #EAEAEA 0%, #D3D3D3 100%); /* firefox */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C4C4C4), color-stop(0%,#EAEAEA), color-stop(100%,#D3D3D3)); /* webkit */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#C4C4C4', endColorstr='#D3D3D3',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
width: 83%;
float: left;
padding: 0 4px;
border-top-left-radius: 4px 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px 4px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px 4px;
}
#tw-form #tw-input-text{
width: 80%;
float: left;
border: 0;
background: #DDDDDD;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4 0%, #EAEAEA 0%, #D3D3D3 100%); /* firefox */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C4C4C4), color-stop(0%,#EAEAEA), color-stop(100%,#D3D3D3)); /* webkit */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#C4C4C4', endColorstr='#D3D3D3',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
color: #777;
line-height: 100%;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-family: font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px;
height:20px;
}
#tw-form #tw-input-text:focus{
outline:none;
color:#333;
}
#tw-form #tw-input-submit{
background: url(search-zoom-icon.png) no-repeat 10px 5px;
border: 0;
float: left;
width: 22px;
z-index: 100;
cursor: pointer;
}
/*Search Bar Ends Here*/
#socialicons {

    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 13.5em;


}
.logo {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -27.5em;
    top: -22em;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

So the About us menu should drop down and when I try it in a file by itself it works perfectly but as soon as I add the image it stops working.

Comment: another question, what is the height of your logo? the width seems too wide to me for a logo. and what you want to achieve with the logo. `.logo` class seems problematic to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your image is over your content
change the logo `z-index` to 0 to send it behind

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -27.5em;
    top: -22em;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLSLD/) with the image sent behind

Comment: I tried both this and the other comment and it still hasn't changed.

Comment: is the site live, so i can take a look? did you check the fiddle link i provided? it works there.

Comment: 1 more thing to add. you have the `.logo` class twice in your document, once in the beginning and once in the end, which means that some of the css rules will be overriden.